# How to make a horizontal set of divs elastic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of 1-4 divs sitting vertically inside of a `<section>`.  There are 4 buttons which decide how many divs will be invoked.  I need the divs to expand to a proportional size, side by side, when they are instantiated.  Here is some HTML and CSS code which relate to this.

[image]

First the HTML5 markup...

```
<section id="main">
  <div id="resultContainer">
    <section id="i0" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day" ></span>
            <span class="temp" ></span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind" ></span><br/> 
        <span class="humid" ></span> 
        <span class="other1" ></span> 
        <span class="other2" ></span> 
    </section>
    <section id="i1" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day"></span>
            <span class="temp"> </span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind" ></span><br/> 
        <span class="humid"></span> 
        <span class="other1"></span> 
        <span class="other2"></span> 
    </section>
    <section id="i2" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day" ></span>
            <span class="temp" </span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind"></span><br/>  
        <span class="humid"></span> 
        <span class="other1"></span> 
        <span class="other2"></span> 
    </section>
    <section id="i3" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day"></span>
            <span class="temp"></span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind"></span><br/>  
        <span class="humid"></span> 
        <span class="other1"></span> 
        <span class="other2"></span> 
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
#main {
filter: none;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
height: 400px;
-webkit-background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.2);
background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.2);
/*background-color: #484848;*/
width: 460px;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}
```

TIA

Dennis

Comment: If you mean to have the columns fill all horizontal space, updating as columns are added/removed, you'll probably find it easiest to put them in a (dare i say it) table. Or have the JS from the buttons apply a class to the columns' container that says how many there are, then do `.cols-3 > .col { width:30%; }` etc

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I think that you may be right.  However, there is so much talk about not using tables any more that I thought I would try to find an answer with the new HTML5 markup.

Comment: I would take a look at flex boxes. If you need legacy support, they won't really work but they are an excellent alternative to the finicky table approach.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes 

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @slicedtoad Thank you for the links.  Looks good so far...  I need to learn more about the flex feature, anyway.  Very appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Since Legacy support was required and I had trouble even with the use of a table, I improvised  a non-CSS only solution.  Clicking on the buttons 1-4 gives me the divisor (nDays) and I used it to divide the width of the container, which gave me the correct width for each div which houses the forecast day div.

```
                dayWidth = parseInt(420/nDays);
                $('#i'+i).css('width',dayWidth);
                $('#i'+i).css('display','inline-block');
```

Works great, without all the convolutions of trying to make CSS do it automatically.

And here is the result.

[image]

Comment: yup, sometimes it's more effort than it's worth to avoid JS for styling.

Comment: wait... Do the daydivs actually need to change size? Your preview has them all the same size. If they don't change size, this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/2ja0gsf7/1/

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I missed the bit about legacy support being required, making this answer not quite appropriate.

CSS solution:

```
#resultContainer{
    table-layout: fixed; /* Stops cell widths varying depending on content */
}

.wDay{
    display:table-cell;  /* Display as table cell. */
    width: 1%;           /* Needs some width to start with */
    text-align: center;  /* centres cell content and balances "table" margins */
}
```

There's no need to put a `display: table;` in the parent div but you could to make it clearer.

Need to check different browsers!

Comment: Actually that is a very interesting solution too.  Thank you, I am taking note of this...

Answer (score 0):

please try this one in css

```
.wDay{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason it was not working.  Maybe I did something wrong.  I will try it again just for the heck of it.  Thanks for the input.